# Как правильно осуществить выборку данных из двух таблиц

Tags: sql, access, join

Существует две таблицы: *FIRM* - организации, *CITY* - города.

В таблице *FIRM* есть поля *FIRM.JUR_CITY_ID* (не может быть пустым) для города юридического адреса и *FIRM.POST_CITY_ID* (может быть пустым) для города почтового адреса.

В таблице *CITY* есть поле *CITY_ID* (*ИД* записи).

Все заполненные   *FIRM.JUR_CITY_ID*, *FIRM.POST_CITY_ID* существуют в таблице *FIRM*.

Кроме этого, в таблицах есть поля *FIRM.NAME* – название организации и   *CITY.NAME* – название города.

Требуется построить *SQL*-запрос, который обеспечивал бы фильтрующий поиск информации по названию организации и по названиям городов почтового и юридического адреса. (Следует учесть, что поля могут заполняться в разных регистрах).

```
SELECT FIRM.FIRM_NAME, JUR_CITY.CITY_NAME, POST_CITY.CITY_NAME
FROM FIRM
  LEFT JOIN CITY JUR_CITY ON (FIRM.JUR_CITY_ID = JUR_CITY.CITY_ID)
  LEFT JOIN CITY POST_CITY ON (FIRM.POST_CITY_ID = POST_CITY.CITY_ID)
WHERE UCase(FIRM.FIRM_NAME) LIKE UCase('Фирма_1')
  OR UCase(JUR_CITY.CITY_NAME) LIKE UCase('Москва')
  OR (POST_CITY.CITY_ID is not null
  AND UCase(POST_CITY.CITY_NAME) LIKE UCase('Москва'))
```

Такой запрос выдает ошибку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Access (и вообще SQL, но Access в особенности) чувствителен к порядку таблиц в LEFT JOIN, и требует явного указания именно двух соединяемых таблиц. Добавьте скобки.

```sql
SELECT FIRM.FIRM_NAME, JUR_CITY.CITY_NAME, POST_CITY.CITY_NAME
FROM (
      FIRM
      LEFT JOIN CITY JUR_CITY ON (FIRM.JUR_CITY_ID = JUR_CITY.CITY_ID)
  )
  LEFT JOIN CITY POST_CITY ON (FIRM.POST_CITY_ID = POST_CITY.CITY_ID)
WHERE UCase(FIRM.FIRM_NAME) LIKE UCase('Фирма_1')
  OR UCase(JUR_CITY.CITY_NAME) LIKE UCase('Москва')
  OR (POST_CITY.CITY_ID is not null
  AND UCase(POST_CITY.CITY_NAME) LIKE UCase('Москва'))
```

Answer (score 0):

При использовании алиаса Access требует использования AS, т.е. замените

LEFT JOIN CITY JUR_CITY

на

LEFT JOIN CITY AS JUR_CITY